# Is it possible to pass an array into a PixelShader register using WPF

Tags: wpf, hlsl

I'm trying to write a Gaussian blur pixel shader for use with WPF Effects, but I'm having difficulties finding a way to pass the kernel into the shader.

The way my shader works is pretty standard. It calculates the kernel on the cpu and then it (tries) to pass it to the gpu for use.

Currently, my kernel is formatted as a float array of size 144 (24x24 kernel with symmetry). From what I've gather, it's not like opengl where I can pass it raw data through a vbo. WPF dependency objects doesn't seem to support array types and hlsl doesn't support native arrays.

I could store the kernel in a texture but I wouldn't know how to generate and then pass that texture. The texture input for shaders seem to be a brush, but I can't find a way to set brush data directly in WPF.

Is passing an array in possible at all? Or do I have to hard code the kernel in the shader? It's such a trivial thing to do in opengl, I can't imagine it's not possible in WPF.